# CSS for printing is not applied to dynamically generated HTML

Tags: css

I am trying to print an HTML that comes from server-side. And the main issue that I face now is that css is not applied for some reason. See the fiddle. Is there something I am doing wrong ?

P.S. The JS with frames is used in order to open the print window in the same tab. Previously I ran into trouble that when new tab opened, the JS on the original tab stopped working till I closed the second tab with print content

https://jsfiddle.net/7L9onps1/

```
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
 .test {
   visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: red;
    color: red;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
  }
}
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector("#print").addEventListener("click", function() {
     var html = '<div class="test">Test</div>';
     print(html);
});

function print(html) {
    // https://www.sitepoint.com/5-jquery-print-page-options/
    document.innerHTML = html;
    $('<iframe>', {
        name: 'myiframe',
        class: 'printFrame'
    }).appendTo('body').contents().find('body').append(html);

    window.frames['myiframe'].focus();
    window.frames['myiframe'].print();
    setTimeout(() => { $(".printFrame").remove(); }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I´m using a libary to do that: https://github.com/DoersGuild/jQuery.print